# how do you round time to the next hour in R

Tags: r

I have data value

```
dput(a)
"1/3/2019 15:59"
```

I need to round the time to to the next hour. I need this date to be `"1/3/2019 16:00"`?

How can I do this?

Comment: @RonakShah, yes by next hour.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `lubridate` `dmy_hm` to convert to datetime object and then use `ceiling_date` to convert it to next hour.

```
library(lubridate)
ceiling_date(dmy_hm("1/3/2019 15:59"), "hour")
#[1] "2019-03-01 16:00:00 UTC"
```

Comment: sorry, I missed important part. I have a data set some of them are even 16:00  and some of them are not even like 16:59. I need to keep the even ones and convert the uneven ones to the next hour. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1471980 this would keep complete hours as it is and only round up other ones. Check `ceiling_date(dmy_hm("1/3/2019 16:00"), "hour")` and `ceiling_date(dmy_hm("1/3/2019 16:59"), "hour")`

Comment: if I use a variable instead of "1/3/2019 16:00", I get this error: "1] "2019-01-03 14:00:00 UTC" NA                       
Warning message:
 1 failed to parse. "

Comment: I also need this ETS, not in UTC

Answer (score 2):

Use `round.POSIXt`.  No packages are used.

```
x <- as.POSIXct("1/3/2019 15:59", format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
round(x + 3600/2 - !(as.numeric(x) %% 3600), "hours")
## [1] "2019-01-03 16:00:00 EST"
```